# Long-running PHP task in background

Tags: php, cron

I am making an website which I need to loop on all database everyday, I am using below command on Godaddy shared hosting , but it not working nothing is logging on "app-output.txt" file.

I am using the CodeIgniter, and saves the file in application/controllers with name "my_task.php" and the "make_payment_cron.php" is also on the same folder.

```
$logFile = 'app-output.txt';
$command = 'php '.dirname(__FILE__).'/make_payment_cron.php';
$command.= ' > "'.$logFile.'" 2>&1';
exec($command);
```

Comment: are you sure that exec command is allowed in your host?
it is not allowed in most of shared host.

Comment: i am not sure, how can i check it is allowed?

Comment: It's possible to run a php script from command line - `php -f phpfile.php`. You can put that in cron

Comment: try executing a simple command , like : `$output = exec('ls -l');echo $output;` and make sure it is allowed or not

Comment: output from above command from hosting is drwx---r-x 12 j8b54854 inetuser 4096 Nov 23 11:25 user_guide

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think you will be able to extensively use resources (i.e. CPU) on a shared hosting plan (you'll most probably get a notice and then banned). The best option will be to rent a dedicated server so that you're the only one using the CPU. More importantly, I recommend you to use a bash script since your only input is a file that exists in the system. You can then trigger start the script or kill it via PHP.